# selecting categories that have products with tag/category

Tags: categories, woocommerce-offtopic

i have a lot of product categories on the website - 100+
some products are tagged as "is_new" via custom field. When that happens that are also automatically assigned to a product category "New". Meaning each product can be assign to its own category + category "New".
When i go to category new in the front end i want users to see all categories that contain "New" products for navigation.

What would be the best way to do that? First select all "new" products and then get a tree from their categories? or is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

Hi im not really experienced but I think you could do this with WP_Query. You can do amazing things with it but I dont know how to use it so I cant give example

Edit after the minute I posted this: I think my answer is completely off topic how can I delete it?